# Proving that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L'$ imply $L=L'$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Exercise: Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $L$ and $L'$ be distinct real numbers. If $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L'$. Prove that $L=L'$.

Proof: Given that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L'$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $N\ge m$ such that for all $n>N$ $$|a_n-L|<\frac \varepsilon 2$$ $$|a_n-L'|=|L'-a_n|<\frac \varepsilon 2$$

Adding the two inequalities together and using the triangle inequality we get $$|a_n-L+L'-a_n|=|-L+L'|<\varepsilon$$

Because $\varepsilon$ was an arbitrary real number $>0$, the above inequality implies that $|-L+L'|=|0|$ and thus $L=L'$.

Is this proof correct?

Edit: I thought I should type this proof better for any future readers through the suggestions that I got.

Proof: Given that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L'$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $N_1\ge m$ and an $N_2 \ge m$ such that for all $n>max\{N_1,N_2\}$ we have the following two inequalities. $$|a_n - L|<\frac \varepsilon 2$$ $$|a_n - L'|=|L'-a_n|<\frac \varepsilon 2$$

Adding the two inequalities together and using the triangle inequality we get $$|a_n-L+L'-a_n|=|-L+L'|<\varepsilon$$

Because the above inequality must hold for every $\varepsilon > 0$, $|-L+L'|$ cannot be non-zero. Thus $|-L+L'|=|0|$ and $L=L'$.

Comment: Formally, it is correct. But the word 'distinct' near the beginning is a bit misleading.

Comment: That line might better read $$|L'-L|=|L'-a_n+a_n-L|\leq |L'-a_n|+|a_n-L|<\epsilon$$ to show how everything comes together.

Comment: @ajotatxe Would the phrasing: Let $L$ and $L'$ be real numbers such that $L\ne L'$ be better?

Comment: It is the same. You _know_ that $L=L'$, so it suffces to say "Let $L$ and $L'$ be two limits of the sequence. _Asume_ that $L\neq L'$ to get a contradiction". Or something like that.

Comment: @ajotatxe Noted!

Comment: I would start with let $\epsilon = |L-L'|$ then when $|a_n - L|<\frac {\epsilon}{2}$ and $|a_n - L'|<\frac {\epsilon}{2}$ you will have a contradiction.

Comment: @DougM Yeah that also works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessarily the same $N$ for $L$ and for $L'$. Otherwise it's all good.

Comment: Yeah, I think i should have said that let $N$ be the max of both inequalities and then proceed.

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is fine. Well done!

But, to be more precise, I would proceed as follows.

Since $(a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is supposed to converge to both $L$ and $L'$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds $n_{1}(\varepsilon)$ and $n_{2}(\varepsilon)$ such that $|a_{n} - L| < \varepsilon$ for every $n\geq n_{1}(\varepsilon)$ and $|a_{n} - L'| < \varepsilon$ for every $n\geq n_{2}(\varepsilon)$.

Consequently, if $L\neq L'$ and $\varepsilon = |L - L'|/3$, one can choose $n(\varepsilon) = \max\{n_{1}(\varepsilon),n_{2}(\varepsilon)\}$ so that for every $n\geq n(\varepsilon)$ one gets the following relation:
\begin{align*}
|L' - L| = |(a_{n} - L) - (a_{n} - L')| \leq |a_{n} - L| + |a_{n} - L'| \leq 2\varepsilon \Rightarrow |L - L'| \leq 0 \Rightarrow L = L'
\end{align*}
which contradicts the original assumption.

**Observation**

Although you have chosen the same $N$ for both limits, there is no harm at doing so because it is the same as taking the maximum between $n_{1}(\varepsilon)$ and $n_{2}(\varepsilon)$ as I have proposed in my solution.

Hopefully this helps!